# Can multiple accounts use same Dropbox, with access control

Tags: accounts, dropbox

There are 7-8 different user of my Dropbox account. we are using the single account in all PC's. I want: 
- Certain users not to view few files.
- Certain Users should not be able to edit few files.
- Only few Users should be able to delete a file or can we check which user or PC deleted a specific file

Please suggest if this can be done on any file sharing software or sky drive etc?

Comment: This isn't how dropbox works if you are sharing one account. Perhaps if you edited in more of how this related to using a particular OS and why you're not just paying for a group dropbox account we might be able to answer this or at least get the question to the correct Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This question is not related to Apple products in any way, it should be migrated elsewhere. P.S. Yes, Dropbox can do exactly what you want it to do but each user will need their own account and you would control what files/folders they can access.

Answer (score 2):

Since you came here to ask this, I'll volunteer that a Mac with OS X and Server configured would host files exactly as you wish. Some users could have read/write access and others read only. You could further restrict shares, folders or files with ACL so that arbitrary files are hidden from all but users that are supposed to see the files.

You might also be able to get dropbox group software or Microsoft skydive to do similar, but we're not the best place for that support or answer.